# forge connector in power automate

Tags: autodesk-forge, power-automate, autodesk-bim360, bim

when i try to connect with the forge connector in power automate, it sayes no items in the folder (bim 360).

[![enter image description here](https:[image]//i.stack.imgur.com/1V1Qg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V1Qg.png)

i expect contact wit bim 360

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible missing steps in your setup. Please check that on your ACC account and project.

1. Go to account admin to enable the Power Automate App. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/autodeskforgedataexc/#how-to-get-credentials
2. Open your Revit model on your acc Project, select either view in the model, create an Exchange and save it to your Sentralfil folder. See https://youtu.be/VNzmxkMze48?t=45